# Building OpenCV libraries from source files

Tags: python, opencv, installation

I have installed `Python 2.7`, but when I try to generate the `OpenCV 2.3.1` project Makefiles using `CMake 2.8`, I get the following message. I am running Windows 7 x86 and using Visual Studio 10.

```
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

I have followed the guide provided at this [link](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).

Answer (score 14):

Yes, this also worked for me.

Check advanced, then manually set the values for the three variables.

In my case:

```
PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = .../python.exe

PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR = .../include

PYTHON_LIBRARY = .../python26.lib
```

Tested with PythonPortable on Windows. (so, no installation required)

Comment: your solution is good in cmake syntax that would be written as: set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE C:/Python32/python.exe)

set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Python32/include)

set(PYTHON_LIBRARY C:/Python32/libs/python32.lib)

Comment: For me, PYTHON_LIBRARY was ../libs/python27.lib

Comment: This also works using Enthought Canopy installed in userspace. I only had to manually configure PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR.

Comment: This helped me to find the solution. I added these variables to `CMakeLists.txt` and I needed to use CMake syntax: `set(variable value)`

Answer (score 3):

Did you install Python in the normal place ( c:\Python2.7 on windows)

Use the Cmake-gui select advanced and it will allow you to set all the values directly

Answer (score 1):

Check the architecture of your installed Python, in my case for example I had Python x86_64 package installed but Cmake was looking for x86. So I believe this Cmake error message has a great potential of improvement.